# WP_POSTMETA - What do these values mean inside the data structure?

Tags: post-meta, meta-query, meta-value

In the wp_postmeta table, I am seeing data in a field called "meta_value".    The structure of the data is confusing.  I am trying to understand what these values mean:

The meta_key field has a value of "_employer_socials"

```
a:4:{i:0;a:2:{s:7:"network";s:8:"facebook";s:3:"url";s:1:"#";}i:1;a:2:{s:7:"network";s:7:"twitter";s:3:"url";s:1:"#";}i:2;a:2:{s:7:"network";s:8:"linkedin";s:3:"url";s:1:"#";}i:3;a:2:{s:7:"network";s:9:"instagram";s:3:"url";s:1:"#";}}
```

Specifically, what does a:4: mean, or s:8, or i:1;a:2:

I see facebook and twitter, and can infer these are related to a companies social media handles, but the structure/format is confusing.  There must be some way to decipher this?

My larger goal is to insert data into this field from an external source, but if I can't make sense of it, how do I do it?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_serialization_format

Answer (score 1):

WordPress will serialize arrays when saving to post meta. The data stored under the key `_employer_socials` in your example looks [like this](https://www.unserialize.com/s/03aaf539-424b-cfc9-cb4a-000056cafe9f):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
                [network] => facebook
                [url] => #
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
                [network] => twitter
                [url] => #
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
                [network] => linkedin
                [url] => #
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
                [network] => instagram
                [url] => #
        )
)
```

When you get the meta, WP will unserialize it for you, and it will look like above:

```
$employer_socials = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_employer_socials', true );
```

You can then just work with the data as a regular array. When saving the array, WP will serialize it for you. Here are some basic functions that you can use as a starting point:

```
/**
 * Updates an existing network, or adds a new one if it does not exist.
 *
 * @param int    $post_id The Post ID to be updated.
 * @param string $network The name of the network to check.
 *
 * @return bool True if an update was made, false otherwise.
 */
function wpse_update_employee_social( $post_id, $network, $url ) {

    $employer_socials = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_employer_socials', true );

    // Update.
    if ( wpse_has_employer_social( $post_id, $network ) ) {
        foreach ( $employer_socials as $key => $employer_social ) {
            if ( $employer_social['network'] === $network ) {
                $employer_socials[ $key ]['url'] = $url;
                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_employer_socials', $employer_socials );
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Add.
        $employer_socials[] = [
            'network' => $network,
            'url'     => $url,
        ];
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_employer_socials', $employer_socials );
        return true;
    }

    // Nothing was updated.
    return false;
}

/**
 * Checks if a given network exists.
 *
 * @param int    $post_id The Post ID to be updated.
 * @param string $network The name of the network to check.
 *
 * @return bool True if the network exits, false otherwise.
 */
function wpse_has_employer_social( $post_id, $network ) {
    $employer_socials = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_employer_socials', true );
    foreach ( $employer_socials as $employer_social ) {
        if ( $employer_social['network'] === $network ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Example of adding a new employee social:

```
wpse_update_employee_social( 5302, 'wpse', 'https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/208214/user1669296' );
```

Example of updating an employee social:

```
wpse_update_employee_social( 5302, 'facebook', '#1234' );
```